# Row not selected once join condition is met?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a query that returns shipping information. There are two types of items that are shipped, drives and keys. Until an item is shipped, it will not be present in the `drive_tracking` table and I've added the `IFNULL`'s there to compensate for that. Here is the query.

```
SELECT a.id AS drive_id, CONCAT(a.drive_capacity, a.drive_unit) AS drive_type, 
IFNULL(d.type,'drive') AS category, IFNULL(d.status,'outbound') AS ship_status
FROM drive_details a
LEFT JOIN copy_details b ON a.id = b.drive_id
LEFT JOIN records c ON b.id = c.copy_id
LEFT JOIN drive_tracking d ON a.id = d.drive_id AND d.status = 'outbound'
WHERE c.identifier = '9956852'
```

Here is a result with no matching rows in the `drive_tracking` table.

```
------------------------------------------
|drive_id|drive_type|category|ship_status|
+----------------------------------------+
|208     |1TB       |drive   |outbound   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

But the problem I have, is that once there is a shipped key present in the `drive_tracking` table I no longer see the drive status only the key.

```
------------------------------------------
|drive_id|drive_type|category|ship_status|
+----------------------------------------+
|208     |1TB       |key     |outbound   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

But I need to return...

```
------------------------------------------
|drive_id|drive_type|category|ship_status|
+----------------------------------------+
|208     |1TB       |drive   |outbound   |
+----------------------------------------+
|208     |1TB       |key     |outbound   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I know the problem is with the left join on the `drive_tracking` table but after everything I've tried I can't find a way to include the drive row.

Row from `drive_details` table.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|id   |date         |capacity|unit |encrypted|status      |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|208  |2017-08-23   |1       |TB   |1        |disconnected|
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Row from `drive_tracking` table.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|id   |drive_id |type |status   |number       |ship_date  |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|134  |208      |key  |outbound |729292222038 |2017-09-10 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi. You are not clear about what you want. Please read & act on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  Please edit clarifications into questions, not comments. PS First show a left join that holds the required info before you start limiting & modifying it in your select clause. Also you could remove b & c and restrict to some a.id(s). We get `SELECT a.id, d.type, d.status
FROM drive_details a
LEFT JOIN drive_tracking d ON a.id = d.drive_id AND d.status = 'outbound'`. Does this hold data you need to generate your desired result? What *do* you need? What *is* your desired result?

Comment: The best way to be clear is to write an appropriate variant of the following sentence describing the query in my previous comment. (Returning relevant intermediate FROM clause data sans b & c.) "(id, type, status) is in the result when /*aliases*/ (a.id, ..) in drive_details & (d.drive_id, ...) in drive_tracking & /*left join*/ (a.id=d.drive_id & d.status='outbound' or not (a.id=d.drive_id & d.status='outbound') & d.status is null)) & /*select*/ id=a.drive_id & ..., /*select*/ for some values of a.* & d.*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case1: no record is joined from drive_tracking and so there is null and so it's giving drive in category. if you put d.status = 'outbound' from join to WHERE condition then I think it will not return any records.

In case 2: One record is left joined from drive_tracking and so it's giving resut like that.

Please run below query and check count for the same.

```
SELECT count(0)
FROM drive_details a
LEFT JOIN copy_details b ON a.id = b.drive_id
LEFT JOIN records c ON b.id = c.copy_id
LEFT JOIN drive_tracking d ON a.id = d.drive_id AND d.status = 'outbound'
WHERE c.identifier = '9956852'
```

It will return 1. It means there is only single record possible with given data.

If you are wishing output as per 3rd one then let me know data present in drive_tracking and drive_details table.

Comment: The count returned is 1. But the problem is that other than the `drive_id`, the `drive_details` and `drive_tracking` table have nothing in common.

Comment: I have added table data. I also tried adding a `type` column to `drive_details` and joining based on that but still couldn't get it right.

Comment: Thanks for putting data. Here it's not possible to get output as 3rd one. And you got drive in case 1 as it's stated above. If you wish to get drive then it's required to have one more record in drive_tracking with drive id = 208 and status not equal to outboud or type is null.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input. I believe I will just add the drives to drive_tracking table before they are shipped then add a shipped column indicating if it was shipped or not. I am going to leave the question open for a while but if I don't get a solution I will accept your answer.

Comment: Please, if you are not sure what a question says, then comment, downvote & close vote but don't answer. Guessing leads to long discussions, answers that aren't answers & unclear questions.